# Python lmfit: Model object trys to use "self" as free variable

Tags: python, curve-fitting, self

I am using the Python module "lmfit" to fit a function to some data. The variables should have constraints and I want to implement the fitting procedure into an existing framework. That is why the fit function has to be a class method. Therefore the first argument of the function should be "self".

```html
import lmfit

class foo(object):

  def __init__(self):
    self.x_data = range(10)
    self.y_data = range(10) + 2

  def fit_func(self, x, a, b):
    return a * x + b
  
  def fit_with_lmfit(self):
    model = lmfit.Model(self.fit_func, independent_vars=["x"])
    model.set_param_hint("a", 1)
    model.set_param_hint("b", 2)
    results = model.fit(self.y_data, x=self.x_data)
    return results
```

But now lmfit interprets "self" as free variable for the fit alogrithm.
I tried adding a parameter hint:

`model.set_param_hint("self", self, vary=False)`

But that results in the following error:

`TypeError: fit_func() got multiple values for keyword argument 'self'`

I know that that `curve_fit()` from scipy.optimize does not has any problems with class methods and neither should `leastsq()`. But I would like to use lmfit since it offers a nice interface to implement constraints for some variables.

On could also define `fit_function()` inside `fit_with_lmfit()` but I need to have access to it from outside the class as well and returning the function alongside `results` seems messy.

So my question would be: is there any way to let lmfit ignore certain variables of a fit function or better yet ignore "self" as positional argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `fit_func` is not using self, make it a static method:

```
@staticmethod
def fit_func(x, a, b):
    return a * x + b
```

This way you don't have to worry about `self`.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. It works perfectly now.